# Drupal 7 giving Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: drupal, google-maps-api-3, drupal-7

**Goal: To render a google map using geolocation.**

I am trying to implement the below example on my site.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding

**Working demo:** http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple.html

I have implemented the code in my drupal_add_js() in hook_init() but I am getting an error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/vishal/public_html/dev/sites/all/modules/customvishal/customvishal.module on line 43

below is my code:

```
drupal_add_js('  
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() 
{
   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
   var myOptions = {
   zoom: 8,
   center: latlng,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

}

var address = "pune,india";
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng();
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status)
{
 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
{
  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker
  ({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
  });
 }
else
{
  alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
}
```

}

);

',
   array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'header', 'weight' => 5)

);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, don't add big gobs of JavaScript inline like that. Put the code in another file and use drupal_add_js() to add the file.

For two, if you're going to ignore that, note that the single quote in the line that starts with `geocoder.geocode` is ending the string. Everything after that is confusing the parser.

Comment: yes it was the single quote that was confusing the parser. I will later put all the js in a sep file too.